Had 1 year visa in Netherlands, then moved to Poland, went back to home country while residence permit was in process. Am I banned in Schengen?
I had a D visa in The Netherlands, I stayed there for 1 year. 1 week before the visa expired I moved to Poland, stayed there for six months, no visa but my residence permit in Poland is on process. I left and went back to my home country without any visa from Poland or residence permit.
Am I banned in Schengen?

Did you received any document to travel from Poland? In Germany for example you need to ask for a specific travel document to travel while having a residence permit application in process.

Yes, I had my working permit when I went to Poland and have 1 week visa left on my dutch visa before I left. While I stay there, I have my yellow card, which means my residence permit is on process.

In Germany, which is not Poland, in many cases a written confirmation of a pending application can serve in place of a residence permit until the decision is made either way (Fiktionsbescheinigung). The question is what Poland does in this regard.
